# Calculate Pixels from View to bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-graphics

I have a layout with a Spinner:

[image]

I would like to get the number of pixels from the top of the spinner to the bottom of the screen. Is there a way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852454/how-to-get-distance-from-the-view-to-a-phone-bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the distance from top of the view, first [find the distance of view from bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31852757/563532) and add the view height

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics(); 
           getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int[] loc = new int[2];
yourView.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
int distance = dm.heightPixels - loc[1];
Int viewHeight = yourView.getHeight()
distance +=viewHeight; //distance from top of the view
```

Comment: Please note you must provide attribution when using [other sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31852757/563532) as a large part of your answer.